# How to find some string from jquery .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to strip all html tags from user input.

This code strip all html tags from `#container`, except anchor and img tags.

```
$("#container").find('*:not(a,img)').each(function() {
     $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
});
```

I can't convert it to find input text .val();

```
$('#inputTxt').val().find('*:not(a,img)').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
});
```

This code shows error :

> $input.val().find() is not a function.

Can someone help me?

---

## Updated POST

well, the example Mr antyrat gave was removing all contents inside any other tags, but I wanted content of them, just removing their tags. so I changed it like this and it's wokring.

```
    var tmpElement = $( $( '#inputTxt' ).val() ); // create tmp HTML node
    tmpElement.find('*:not(a,img)').each(function() {
         $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
    });
    return tmpElement.html();
```

---

### PROBLEM

above code works well with some inputs like these:

1. `<div> Hello <a href="#"> I am a link </a> </div>`
2. `<a href="#" ></a><div>Hello<img src="url" /></div>`

but when user types something like this:

1. `<div><a <div ></div> href="#" ></a></div>`

the output is : `<a <div=""> href="#" >Another link</a>`

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kyu6/4/)

Comment: You want to strip all tags? And then do what? Get hacked?

Comment: What kind of element is `#input` (`input`, `textarea`, `div`, etc.)?

Comment: To clarify your question then, you're looking to strip all HTML tags out of an arbitrary string captured from a `input` element?

Comment: Yes, it looks input .val() and strip it's tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hapens because [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method returns input value, not the jQuery object, and this value doesn't have method [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

In your code:

```
$(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
```

`this` is reference to jQuery element, not Node so you can't get `innerHTML`.

Also if `inputTxt` is input element you can't find any elements inside it as they are just plain text. You need to convert them to HTML at first, for example:

```
var tmpElement = $( $( '#inputTxt' ).val() ); // create tmp HTML node
tmpElement.find( '*:not(a,img)' ).remove(); // remove everything except <a> and <img> elements
$('#inputTxt').replaceWith( tmpElement ); // replace input to it's HTML content
```

But you need to be sure that input has correct HTML in it and has at least one root node. So better is to wrap your HTML into container, `<div>` for example:

```
    var tmpElement = $( '<div>' + $( '#inputTxt' ).val() + '</div>' ); // create tmp HTML node
```

So the main problem you have is that you are trying to iterate over plain string like on elements.

See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kyu6/) on jsFiddle.

**Update:**

Event better is not to remove node w/ contents but just elements:

```
tmpElement.find( '*:not(a,img)' ).contents().unwrap(); // remove everything except <a> and <img> elements
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kyu6/1/)

Comment: That explains why the OP's code doesn't work, but doesn't really provide any help in how to make it work.

Comment: The OP wants everything that is NOT an `<a>` or an `<img>` tag stripped. keeping only those tags

Comment: i am looking for a code to remove all html tags except a and img.

Comment: @aliA I've updated my answer w/ jsFiddle + one more demo is in comments above

Answer (score -1):

`.val()` returns a string, which is not a group of jquery objects, so `.find()` function doesn't work.

try:

```
$('#inputTxt').find('*:not(a,img)').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `.find()` doesn't search inside input element values.